# how do i check for mysql database table field value in creating a query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
if($_SESSION['usergroup']==1) { //admin
    $result = mysql_query("the select statement which is written a certain way. this part is not what question is about") or die(mysql_error());
}

else if($_SESSION['userid']==1013) { //managers
    $result = mysql_query("the select statement which is written a certain way. this part is not what question is about") or die(mysql_error());
}

else { //everyone else
    $result = mysql_query("the select statement which is written a certain way. this part is not what question is about") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

so what i would like to do is to change this line here:

```
else if($_SESSION['userid']==1013) {
```

i want to check if the logged in user has a value of 1 in the user_table in a field called manager.  the pseudo code would be something like:

```
else if(user_table manager field == 1) {
```

or

```
else if(if logged in user has a value of 1 in the manager field of the user_table table) {
```

does this sound like something that can be done?

what i'm trying to accomplish is to edit users and make certain users managers, but i don't want to have to keep editing php files to keep adding those new users every time i make a user a manager.  i just want the users that have been upgraded to have access to that middle query automatically.

here is what i don't want to do...

```
else if($_SESSION['userid']==1013 || $_SESSION['userid']==1014 || $_SESSION['userid']==1015 || $_SESSION['userid']==1016) {
```

...and keep adding and adding to this line in this fashion.

Comment: make your question understandable

Comment: Why hard-code user IDs into your script? Like you've said, it's a serious ain. Why are you not storing user details in your database, and checking at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely sounds like something that can be done.  I would use something like this, using PDO to prepare and then execute the statement.

```
//Prepare the SQL query, using the :user_id parameter which you'll supply in the next statement
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT manager FROM user_table WHERE userid = :user_id');
//Execute the SQL, supplying the parameter
$stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $_SESSION['userid'])'
//Retrieve the value
$manager_role = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

**Or, you can do the same thing without using PDO by preparing your SQL query before running it.**

```
$sql_query = 'SELECT manager FROM user_table WHERE userid = ' . $_SESSION['userid'];
$manager_role =  = mysql_query($sql_query);
....
//Your original code
if($_SESSION['usergroup']==1) { //admin
$result = mysql_query("the select statement which is written a certain way. this part is not what question is about") or die(mysql_error());
}

else if($manager_role == 1) { //managers
    $result = mysql_query("the select statement which is written a certain way. this part is not what question is about") or die(mysql_error());
}

else { //everyone else
    $result = mysql_query("the select statement which is written a certain way. this part is not what question is about") or die(mysql_error());
}

....
```

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know the non pdo way?  i know, i know.  i should really be using pdo format, but most of app is already done.  just trying to make this part more efficient and self sustaining.

Comment: Sure @leoarce!  I've updated the answer to reflect that option as well.